# Multiple imputation multi-level time series (panel) data

Tags: r, panel-data, multiple-imputation

I have a dataset with 4 variables and 5372 units. I want to impute missing values using multiple imputation. What is the best way to do that since I'm working with longitudinal data?

Here is an example of how my dataset is organized:

```r
Data <- data.frame(id = c("africa", "africa", "africa","europa", "europa", "europa", "america", "america", "america"), 
year = c(1980, 1981, 1982,1980, 1981, 1982, 1980, 1981, 1982), 
var1 = c(1, 8, 3, NA, 1, NA, 3, 1, NA), 
var2 = c(1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 10, NA, 12))
```

Comment: This link will come in handy: https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/multiple-imputation-models-for-multilevel-data.html.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/101235/44269) to the question [Handling missing data in a time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/101178/44269).

Comment: Thanks! My problem is that I have missing values in all variables and I want to impute all of them. Is it possible to do that with multiple imputation? In the book example, only one of them has missings and the others are used to predict a model.

Comment: Maybe you can try the package: Amelia. See this in https://opr.princeton.edu/workshops/Downloads/2018Jan_AmeliaPratt.pdf